How to make continuous consumer in Kafka?
If I have a service that takes the name of a topic from the database and starts consuming it, it works! But if I add 1 more topic to this topic list that I'm passing on to the consumer, they won't be able to read it.
In short, a dynamic consumer, who starts consuming topics as they are added. Would this be possible to do without needing it for my service? If not, what would be the best practice to solve this problem?
I expected this consumer to be updated and start consuming messages from the new topic.

KafkaConsumer polling in a while loop already is continuous... You're asking a question about how to query a database and notify another process... not a Kafka question.
Solution
Use threads. One to read the database config and stick it in a Timer. Use that to manage one (or more) consumer thread instance(s) that accepts a list of topics as an input parameter (hint: KafkaConsumer already accepts a Collection or regex Pattern).
See Javadoc section Multi threaded processing for a good starting point, or use libraries like Spring-Kafka/Quarkus/Vert.x/Alpakka to manage this better.
Pseudocode
consumerThread = new ThreadConsumer(baseConfig)  // bootstrap server, group.id, etc.
// TODO: Consider using ThreadPools and many instances

while true:
  sleep(30000)  // Check every 30 seconds
  topics = database.getTopics()
  if consumerThread.topics == topics:
     continue   // same topics, do nothing
  if consumerThread.running:
      try:
        consumerThread.stop()
      except Err:
        log.error("Unable to stop consumer")
   consumerThread.topics = topics
   consumerThread.start()

